# Insert html text into the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am using editor to insert text into the database.

When I enter following:
Your feedbacks are valuable to us.       And saved into the database

When viewing the text I got follwoing:
Your feedbacks are valuable to us.<br>

Is there a way to remove these (.<br&gt) characters from the text while viewing.
Also if a user enters a text into the different color with Bold or italics.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable rich-text features of the editor so that HTML tags and characters don't get added to the content.